# file_uploads is on in the server but shows off in xcart installation

Tags: php, file-upload, ini, x-cart

The link to the site is http://64.37.106.37/. It shows file_uploads as zero. I have printed the value of file_uploads on the top and it is displaying 1. I have also checked it in the control panel and there also its showing On. I have checked the code and nowhere the value of file_uploads is overwritten. What can be the solution to this?

Comment: sorry to say that but English please.....

Answer (score 1):

You should check php.ini and .htaccess files, not just a control panel (whatever that may be).

To verify what's in php.ini and what's overridden locally, create a new php file containing:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This will list all of your directives, search for 'upload' and see what the values are. If it's set to 0 in your php.ini, update that. Otherwise for locally different values, search through .htaccess files for a `php_value` or `php_admin_value` message.

If there is no .htaccess file in the web root, try creating one with `php_admin_value file_uploads 1` in it.

Comment: Thank you Rudi.I created the phpinfo file, uploaded it and executed it and it was displaying nothing. I talked to the server admin regarding this. He did some changes on the server and now it is working fine.